# How to supply command line arguements to a form on launch?

Tags: c#, command-line, startup, launching-application

I have a a simple GUI App, which need to perform a certain function on start-up, but not on manual launch from desktop or start menu. To incorporate this function, I thought of supplying command line arguments to the application, so that depending on the command line argument, we can differentiate between launch on start up and manual launch.
 My Question is that how do I make sure that whenever the user clicks the applications icon on his desktop, the required command line arguments are given to the program.
I am using C# to program my application and want to run it on windows 7

Comment: What operating system? What language? We need more details.

Comment: I am using C# and operating system is windows 7 64 bit

Comment: This is not the same question! My question is different. I want that the arguements be passed when launching app from startup, not from another app.

Comment: The usual design pattern is to use the command line arguments on startup, not when the user clicks the application.  You generally control the startup command and can specify the extra command line arguments (because you are either writing a registry key or creating a shortcut in the Startup directory), but you cannot guarantee that a desktop shortcut will not be manually created by a user. N

Comment: @jbeldock Can you please elaborate on this in the form of an answer.

Comment: Sure, done!   Hope that helps.

Comment: @Pratik, [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/413939/how-to-start-a-program-with-command-line-arguments-on-windows-cmd-with-start) + [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401661/how-to-get-the-command-line-arguments-in-windows-forms) will get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common design pattern for Windows applications which can be launched either at startup (i.e., automatically) or manually (i.e., when a user launches the application) is to pass a command line argument **when the application is launched at startup** but not when a user launches it manually.  Why?   Because you control the mechanism by which the application is started automatically (for example, because you create a registry key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`).  So, for example, you could add a value of `"c:\program files\MyCompany\MyApp.exe" /Startup` And then you could check for the `startup` argument in your code:

```
bool isStartupLaunch;
foreach (string arg in args)
   isStartupLaunch |= (arg.toLower() == "/startup");
```

By contrast, you never really can control how a user is going to launch your application. Maybe they double click on a shortcut, but maybe they double click on your actual executable, or maybe they open a command prompt and launch that way.  So you don't want to rely on getting a specific command line argument when the **user** launches your app.  Much safer to look for the automatic launch, because you control how that is done, and therefore can control the command line arguments passed in.